# Thank you for the new meta!

Tags: discussion

This post is just to express gratitude to the team for the work they put in to splitting up the metas. The new Meta is awesome! :D

May your lives be long and filled with waffles!

Comment: What kind of waffles???

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson bacon flavored waffles.

Comment: Thank you! Now please fix all the problemz before I bite someone's head off!

Comment: Why is this comment box so large?!?!

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson Space good.

Comment: @Manishearth [Space around buttons bad.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229763/223030)

Comment: You called *me?* :P