# Your buttons are much too big!

Tags: bug, design, whitespace

Meta SE seems to have some size issues at the moment. Not only are [tags blessed with *excess* excess whitespace](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229744/223030), but clickable buttons are overly padded:

> [image]
>   <sub>My God... it's full of space!</sub>

Also reproducible on the <kbd>Add Comment</kbd> button down there. And the <kbd>Post Your Answer</kbd> button. And the <kbd>Save Edits</kbd> button. And basically any other button you see.

---

Oh my goodness... the poor [about page](/about)...

> [image]

Boost the font size or *something!*

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kY84MRnxVzo

Comment: And tags are too small. AND THIS COMMENT BOX (textarea) IS SO UGLY!

Comment: Cut the top bar in about half size perhaps too?

Comment: OH YEAH? Well, yo button so big, it's TOUCH-SCREEN FRIENDLY!

Comment: @Shog9 For all those people with touchscreens and no mice on the desktop site out there.

Comment: @JasonC, so, me, half the time.

Comment: The textarea font size is also ginormous.

Comment: Seeing your "SPAAAAAAACE" comment makes me think of Jay, David and Joel on the podcast. *Spaaaaaaaaace!*